# Trovare l'accento tonico di una parola

Tags: grammar, accents

Data una parola qualsiasi, eccezioni a parte, è possibile calcolare in modo automatico dove cade l'accento tonico? E.g. "vocabolario" → "vocabol**à**rio". Esiste qualche riferimento in letteratura che tratti la questione in modo approfondito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, non è possible. L'italiano è una lingua con l'accento libero, al contrario e.g. del latino in cui l'accento era completamente determinato dalla lunghezza delle vocali.

Perciò l'unico modo di scoprire l'accento tonico è cercare in un dizionario.

Fonte: Serianni, *Grammatica*, I.§174-176, che dà anche una serie di indicazioni approssimative per determinare l'accento in alcuni casi particolari (e.g. i nomi in *-aggine* sono sempre sdruccioli).

Comment: Che dire delle parole derivate, invece, come le forme verbali? Si può dire che quelle siano più regolari nel limite delle corrispondenti coniugazioni?

Comment: @giofrida Sì, almeno per i verbi regolari l'accento nelle forme coniugate è determinato dalla posizione dell'accento all'infinito (per esempio guarda la tabella delle coniugazioni nel libro di Serianni). Per i verbi irregolari ovviamente non è possibile dare regole...